# Unity 2d Character hitting object with different direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, character, collision-detection

Hi guys I want to ask how can I set a .addforce with different direction when my character hits the objects. My character is kicking left and right and i want the object to go to different direction with different force. And i want my character not hitting the object when it`s running.

[Here is my character and I have 2 box collider for the feet and for the trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tbtW.png)

Here is my code for the force.

```
    Public void Sipa()
{
   if (canSipa == true)
  {
        _pitcha.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(1000, 5000));
        //_pitcha.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.right * kickForce);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Public doesn't exist, try `public` instead. Unity has functions that you can override, in this case try using the following:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Tag of object that is expected to collide") {
        _pitcha.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(1000, 5000));
    }
}
```

Comment: I`ll try it, I will comment if it was successful.

Comment: Still not effective, the object is just sticking on the object when i kicking `void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "_player")
        {
            _pitcha.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(1000, 5000));
        }
    }`

Comment: Can you check if it worked? A common error is forgetting about rigidbody on both objects.

Comment: Is there any possible way you can check my project? Because I have my rigidbody for both of my character and object and i use box collider for the foot of my character and circle collider for the object

Comment: That would be pretty difficult here, but if you have twitter or something like that you can send me some screenshots!

Comment: Yup I have facebook, can I get your name sir ?

Comment: @Mavvvv In the picture you set your collider on the player to be a trigger. You have to use `OnTriggerEnter2D` instead.

Comment: @SwiftingDuster you are right! He's using trigger. I would recommend to check if it is a good idea to use trigger tho... For what I've seen it should not be trigger. More even if you are applying forces to the object.

Comment: Ow ya. Doing it now and will try it.

Comment: Also Change Collision2D to Collider2D

Comment: I'm seeing two colliders though, one just a normal collider and one trigger. Should've worked either way, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Still no luck guys :(

Comment: [https://ibb.co/nFCutV]
[https://ibb.co/nFCutV] but the code here is working and only hit it with one direction